# Can you help me understand the cache behaviour on an ARM Cortex-A9?

Tags: caching, arm, cortex-a

I tried to understand what was going on during a LOAD and/or STORE instruction. Therefore I performed 4 tests, and each time, I measured the number of cpu cycles (CC) /cache hits (CH) /misses (CM)/data reads (DR)/writes (DW).

After reading the different counters, I just flush the L1 (I/D cache).

Test1:

```
LDRB    R3, [R4,#1]!
STR     R3, [SP,#0x48+var_34]

Results: 4 (CC) 3(CH) 1(CM) 1(DR) 2(DW)
```

Test2:

```
 LDR     R3, [SP,#0x48+var_34]
 LDR     R3, [R3]

 Results: 4 3 1 2 1
```

Test3:

```
LDR     R3, [SP,#0x48+var_38]
LDR     R3, [R3]
STR     R3, [SP,#0x48+var_30]

Results: 4 4 1 2 2 
var_30 is returned at the end of the current function.
```

Test4:

```
LDR     R2, [SP,#0x48+var_34]
LDR     R3, [R2] 

Results: 4 3 1 2 1
```

Here is my understanding:

**1. Cache misses**

In each test we have 1 cache miss because when one performs

```
LDR reg, something
```

"Something" is going to be cached, and there will be a cache miss.

And... that's pretty much the only "logical" interpretation I could make...
I do not understand the different values for the cache hits, data reads, and data writes.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the arm documentation at infocenter.arm.com spells out quite clearly what happens on the axi/amba bus in the amba/axi documentation.  Now processor to L1 is tightly coupled, not amba/axi, all within the core.  If you are only clearing the L1 then the L2 may still contain the values so one experiment compared to others may show different results if the L2 misses or not. Also you are not just measuring the load and store but the fetch of the instructions too, and their alignment will change the results even with two instructions if the cache line is between them the performance may differ than if they were together.  there are experiments to do just with that based on alignment within a line as to when and if another cache line fetch goes out.

Also trying to get deterministic numbers on processors like these are a bit difficult, particularly with the cache on.  If you are running these experiments on anything but bare metal, they there is no reason to expect any kind of meaningful results.  With bare metal the results are still suspect, but can be made to be more deterministic.

If you are simply trying to understand cache basics not specific to the arm or any other platform then just google that, go to wikipedia, etc.  TONS of info out there.  Cache is just faster ram, closer to the processor in time as well as being fast (more expensive) sram.  So quite simply the cache looks at your address, looks it up in a table or set of tables and determines hit or miss, if a hit then it returns the value or accepts the write data and completes the processor side of the transaction (allowing the processor to continue but then goes to write the cache, fire and forget basically).  if a miss then it has to figure out if there is a spare opening in the cache for this data, if not it has to evict something by writing it out, then or if there was already an empty spot it can do a cache line read which is often larger than the read you asked for.  That hits the l2 in the same way as the l1, hit or miss evict or not and so on, until it either hits a cache layer that gets a hit or until it hits the final ram or peripheral where it gets the data from.  then that is written to all the cache layers on the way back to the l1 and then the processor gets its little bit of data it asked for.  If the processor asks for another data item in that cache line now it is in l1 and returns really fast.  l2 is usually bigger than l1 and so on such that everything in l1 is in l2 but not everything in l2 is in l1, so that you can evict from l1 to l2 and if then something comes along it may miss l1 but hit l2 and still be much faster than going to slow dram.  It is a bit like keeping the tools or reference materials or whatever you use most often closer to you at your desk and things you keep less often further away since there isnt room for everything, as you change projects or evolve what is used most often and least often changes and there position on the desk change.

Comment: ok I will check the axi/amba spec.

I also flush the L2 right now and the values CC/CH/CM/DR/DW are quite stable now.

For instance, for the 4th test, I'm getting 4 3 2 2 1.

Comment: you're right about when you say "there is no reason to expect any kind of meaningful results". i'll try to perform the test with bare metal.

 I understood the cache basics (almost), i'm just trying to get a better understanding of the cache behaviour on the current platform I'm working on (ARM cortex-A9).

Comment: the l1 is usually part of the core which is a technical reference manual at arms website for the specific core you are using.  the l2 is an add on item if you have one which hopefully the chip vendor has specified, also a separate technical reference manual from arms website.  then anything beyond that is chip vendor specific and you have to go to the chip vendor for that if it matters.

Comment: to try to get results that mean something you need to start probably with a clean cache, try to choose addresses that are not lined up with something the test program is accessing, stuff like that, to do data caching you need the mmu enabled and with that you can enable caching only on the data address space under test and leave the rest uncached even the instructions.  although the instructions play into the results so you need to control the offset of the instructions where they land in a cache line move that around in your experiments

Comment: you also perhaps do want to enable the i cache, call the instructions under test in a function using either an address not in the d cached space or after calling then flush the cache but basically you want to get the instructions in the I cache, get those transfers all settled, then do the dcache instructions such that only the dcache latencies are being measured.  Unless you want both I and D cache latencies to be applied.  If the i and d are enabled and you have not run/cached them until the first execution of those instructions under test

Comment: then you end up with one or two or more cache lines of instruction fetching into the l1/l2 caches then you get the d cache penalties for the data transfer.  the l2 arm caches I am familiar with are both I and D so you need to be careful not to have instructions that are part of the test line up in a way to conflict with the data addresses you are using.  the best way to do all of this is to use the mmu, have the instructions for the load/store and the data addresses cache enabled in the mmu and all other code and data not.

Comment: now using the mmu also has its own penalties and its own cache (cant remember what it is called) .  But the mmu has to walk its table which is also in ram (but not cache through the l1/l2) which is a side effect of these transfers, I fetches and Data accesss.  So that adds into your time as well, and if you dont manage the mmu accessing things repeatedly or not then that messes with the accuracy of your measurements.  the mmu is documented in the arm core technical reference manual.